# Command to execute sqlite select statement in python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have below sqlite query

```
SELECT EMP_CODE, FullName FROM EmpMaster
```

I have below code in python

I will then create CSV/xlsx file on the data extracted. Kindly provide python code for select statement.

Comment: "I have below code in python" and then there's no python code at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQL statements directly python,

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="yourusername",password="yourpassword",database="mydatabase")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT EMP_CODE, FullName FROM EmpMaster")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
```

for more on mysql check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp)

Comment: for sqlite3 you need to import that and connect to the sqlite3 database `import sqlite3`

`conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')` adn you can execute the query as shown above